# How to get HTML file from firebase storage bucket and display it on React Page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase-storage, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have tried a few things such as dangerouslySetInnerHTML and nothing has worked. This is my latest attempt...

```
this.state={article:"firebaseStorageLinkToHTML"}

createMarkup(){ return {__html: this.state.article}; };
return(
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()} />
)
```

When this code is ran all I see on the screen is firebaseStorageLinkToHTML.
Any suggestions?